# Online Messaging: <ul> vs <ol> vs <div>

Tags: html, semantics

I'm busy writing an online chat, and although it doesn't really matter which I use, since I can style them however I want with CSS, I'd quite like to use the best tag for messages.

My first thought was to use an `<ol>` since the messages are *ordered by time*. However, Facebook uses `<ul>`s and Google chat uses `<div>`s. Twitter does use `<ol>`.

So, which is semantically correct?
And, which would be best for user with screen readers?

Answer (score 1):

`div` only. `<ul><ol>` are lists. Chat messages are not ordered list, it is obvious. If you dont need bullets/dots/other marker near each message - they are not unordered list too.

Also using `div` you dont need to reset default styles for lists = less CSS code you will write.

Comment: Why are they not lists? I have a list of messages, don't I? (Un)ordered lists are not defined as using bullets/numbers, that is simply their default style. Try to separate display from semantics here. The change in the amount of CSS code is negligible

Comment: Formally they are lists too. But what is the point to use 'ul/ol' if you reset all default styles (remove list-style-type, remove default margin/padding)? Answers on stackoverflow are lists too, but list tag is not used. However twitter use '<ol>' for tweets. But i advise to use 'div' if you reset default styles and '<ol/ul>' if you just customise it.

Comment: This confusion because the standard does gives definition for list. So for moot issues i prefer to use more convenience markup for me.

Comment: Because `<ol>`/`<ul>` have semantic meaning, but `<div>` doesn't. I'm open to the idea of using `<div>`s, but you haven't presented a convincing argument