# Form div vs ul how to choose?

Tags: html, css

What the different between using ul to using div for forms?
I tried them both and I see no difference, so which?

Here is a snippet that I took (and this I change also from ul to div):

```
    <ul class="flex-outer">
          <li>
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="first-name" placeholder="Enter your first name here">
          </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Online Messaging: <ul> vs <ol> vs <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966272/online-messaging-ul-vs-ol-vs-div)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why should I use 'li' instead of 'div'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549689/why-should-i-use-li-instead-of-div)

Comment: Because it improve the readability of your HTML code, and it also applies meaning to content which would otherwise have none. [Here Read This](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/unordered-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<li>` will work inside both `<div>` and `<ul>`, as you've noted.  However the only acceptable child element of a `<ul>` is `<li>`, whereas practically anything can be a child of a `<div>`.

Otherwise, the differences are mainly semantic.  If you have CSS that only affects lists, or simply to keep your lists distinct within the DOM, use `<ul>` (or `<ol>`).  Use `<div>` when you require a more flexibile, generic container.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend these two resources:

- [How to structure an HTML form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form)
- [Are HTML forms required to display form input controls?](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2435-are-html-form-tags-required-to-display-form-input-controls.htm)

From the second link:

> That said, it seems that using a FORM tag does have some benefits, depending on your particular situation:
>
> - You need it if you want to execute a traditional (ie. non-AJAX) form post.
> - You need it you want to capture the "submit" event programmatically.
> - You need it in order for mobile Safari to show the "Go" button on the keyboard.
> - You need it if you want to programmatically "reset" a form (ie. call reset()).
> - It makes generic form serialization easier (since it groups input fields).
> - You need it if you want to post files without the modern file API.
>   You need it if you have to segregate fields with the same name.

Of course you can always use `div`s and `ul`s with `li`s in a form, but that is completely up to you, design wise. You would probably want to use list items if your form is going to look like a list - this would help with styling it. If not, you can group together your `labels` and `inputs` with `divs`. But functionality wise, there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

you can build a site with `<div>` only. its flexible element but we use different elements like `<h2>` `<span>` & ... to make our syntax readable using `<li>` have padding bad habits that you should neutralize them and also `<ul>` list style. I can't remember more difference between them